# opencv - resizeWindow do nothing?

Tags: opencv, resize, window

I tried  some variations but it seem that resizeWindow don't do anything.
I give simple code example,the result is that the 2 windows are in the same size , eventough it supposed to be in different sizes.

```
Mat m = imread("somePath",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 
namedWindow("aa",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
namedWindow("bb",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("aa",m);
imshow("bb",m);
resizeWindow("aa",400,400);
resizeWindow("bb",800,800);
waitKey(0);
```

I work  with eclipse-cdt on ubunto 12.04 with opencv 2.4.3.

- I tried to debug it,getting into the the function but I don't succeed to add highGui modoul  as external source, i get compile error of some h file missing.

Answer (score 9):

The following code snippet works for me:

```
namedWindow("Final", 0);
resizeWindow("Final", 500,500);
```

"Only windows created without CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE flag can be resized."

REF: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#resizewindow

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that OpenCV is installed with Qt backend support.

Quote from [the documentation of `namedWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=resizewindow#namedwindow) (emphasis is mine):

> flags – Flags of the window. **Currently the only supported flag is
>   CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE**. If this is set, the window size is automatically
>   adjusted to fit the displayed image (see imshow() ), and you cannot
>   change the window size manually.
>
> ...
>
> **Note: Qt backend supports additional flags: CV_WINDOW_NORMAL or
>   CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE**: CV_WINDOW_NORMAL enables you to resize the window,
>   whereas CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE adjusts automatically the window size to
>   fit the displayed image (see imshow() ), and you cannot change the
>   window size manually.

It is likely that `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` is the only supported flag on your system. [Documentation for `resizeWindow`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=resizewindow#cv.ResizeWindow) says that only windows created **without** `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` flag can be resized. Your options are:

- install OpenCV with Qt backend, or
- use `resize()` function to resize the image before displaying it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had that problem too, the bottom line is OpenCV windows have a minimum size and both of those windows you try to create fall below it. I am reasonably certain your picture areas are also clipped, possibly with either gray, or other bogus information.

Comment: as I said I tried some variations. i fix the code so the sizes are 400 and 800, nothing change.

Comment: depends on your installation, see the post below.